# sudo is messing path order

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm having a little issue with my `PATH` when I use `sudo` :

My `PATH` from user shell :

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin
```

My `PATH` from root shell, via `su` or root login on TTY :

```
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

My `PATH` from root shell, via `sudo -s` :

```
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/bin
```

As you can see, when using `sudo`, the order of `/bin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` is reversed.

It's quite annoying, mainly when I use Vim. I'm used to having `vi` a symlink to `vim`. The configuration of symlinks on my Gentoo system is :

```
/bin/vi     -> busybox
/usr/bin/vi -> vim
```

So in most cases, simply typing `vi` brings up Vim, but if I use `sudo vi`, I end up with the Busibox vi, due to change in `PATH` order !

I couldn't find out how `sudo` builds this new path, is there a way to change it ?

Comment: do you use /bin/vi ? You could maybe symlink it to /usr/bin/vi

Comment: @user1281385 This symlick is part of the internal Gentoo system, and might be useful in recovery situations. I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the /etc/sudoers file or /etc/sudoers.d directory.  You should see something like:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: I didn't have such a line, but adding it with correct order did the trick.